# Detach panel like Font Face Ninja or CSS Peeper in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to have a detached panel like Font Face Ninja or CSS Peeper for a Chrome Extension. Tried googling but don't know what that thing is called. Here are there screenshots.

## Font Face Ninja

[image: font face ninja]

## CSS Peeper

[image: css peeper]

Notice the popup. I want it to be like that. And movable too like Font Face Ninja does it. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the popup that the font face ninja creates and inspect you will see this is appended to the DOM of the page you are on. You can see the markup in the screenshot below. This is not part of the chrome extension as such but custom HTML, CSS and JS to create an interactive panel.

[image]

Comment: woah, never would've thought of that but how would I add it? do I directly append it to the DOM using something like `document.appendChild`?

Comment: To modify a web page you need a content script. If the UI is complex, use ShadowDOM or iframe element and web_accessible_resources, there are tutorials on doing both in a chrome extension.